# How to stay in website online for all day using remote PC

Tags: remote-desktop, web, browsing

I want to stay online in a website always, I mean 24/7 but I don't want to do this on my PC. Because I need to turn off my PC sometimes. In which way I can achieve this ? One solution comes to my mind is cloud based OS solution that I login and run any browser login that page and stay online, but couldn't find easy working one?

I am willing to pay small amount for such service. Searched all over internet couldn't find effective answer.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can sign up for [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) (Amazon Web Services) and run a VM in the cloud. There is a 2 week free trial and a ton of documentation how to set it up. I used to have a vm with server 2012 on it with AWS and I recall it being about $16 dollars (USD) a month for 1 virtual core on 1 processor and the minimal specs.

Comment: Thanks for answer Narzard, is my browser kept open even when I turned off my PC ?

Comment: Yes. The virtual machine never turns off. Whatever you have open, will stay open even if you turn off your personal machine.